# Tkinter: Window not showing image

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to GUI programming and recently started working with tKinter.

My problem is that the program won't show my image, I'm suspecing that it is my code that is wrong, however, I would like somone to exactly explain to me how i can make it work...

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *  # Import the tkinter module (For the Graphical User Interface)
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

width = 1920
height = 1080
RootGeo = str(width) + "x" + str(height)  # Make a def for RootGeo so the Root geometry isn't hardcoded


def MakeWindow():
    # -----Root_Attributes-----

    Root = Tk()
    Root.geometry(RootGeo)
    Root.state("zoomed")

    # -----Root_Attributes, Root_Containers----- ### NOT WORKING ###
    __DISPlAY__ = Image.open("Display.png")
    __DISPLAY_RENDER__ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(__DISPlAY__)

    Display_icon = Label(Root, image=__DISPLAY_RENDER__)
    Display_icon.image = __DISPLAY_RENDER__
    Display_icon.place(x=0, y=0)
    # -----Root_Containers----- ### NOT WORKING ###

    Root.mainloop()


MakeWindow()
```

Any and all help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: not a duplicate....

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry if i have mistaken, But i do not understand that post, Could someone in detail explain it to me?

Comment: I was mistaken. I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok... But could you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Any errors showing up in the console? Like `_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "zoomed": must be normal, iconic, or withdrawn` for example?

Comment: when I run your code, the image shows exactly as I would expect it to.

Comment: @Aran-Fey no i do not get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the image and check out if its still not showing up.
if its still not showing up, try to change this line:

`__DISPlAY__ = Image.open("Display.png")`

to

`__DISPlAY__ = Image.open("Display.png").resize((600,800))`

see if it would show up now then change the width and height as you like.

Comment: The image does not even show up, and the directory is correct

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the cmd return an error, or a window appears with no image in it ?

Comment: yes. A window appears without any errors but the image is not shown,

Answer (score 0):

Pychamarm does not want to show the images, so to solve this problem i had to run the script from cmd every time...