# Why isn't anything showing in my Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to GUI programming and im trying to make my first GUI program, However. For some reason nothing will show on the frame. The frame is successfuly made, yet i cant show any image on it. I've also tried making a button with no further success. Sorry if this is something obvious, but like i earlier said i do not have any experiance with gui programming in python.

```
from tkinter import *  # Import the tkinter module (For the Graphical User Interface)
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

width = 1920
height = 1080
RootGeo = str(width) + "x" + str(height)  # Make a def for RootGeo so the Root geometry isn't hardcoded


def MakeWindow():
    # -----Root_Attributes-----

    Root = Tk()
    Root.geometry(RootGeo)
    Root.state("zoomed")

    # -----Root_Attributes, Root_Containers----- ### NOT WORKING ###
    __DISPLAY_DIRECTORY__ = "C:\Users\Gotta\PythonProjects\AutoCam\Settings.gif"
    __DISPlAY__ = Image.open(__DISPLAY_DIRECTORY__).resize((50, 50))
    __DISPLAY_RENDER__ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(__DISPlAY__)

    Display_icon = Label(Root, image=__DISPLAY_RENDER__)
    Display_icon.pack()
    # -----Root_Containers----- ### NOT WORKING ###

    Root.mainloop()


MakeWindow()
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249500/tkinter-window-not-showing-image

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, pycharm does not want to show images in a tkinter frame. The solution was then to save the Pycharm file and then run the script from cmd.